# Adding arraylist data to listview

Tags: android

I have to display a list of messages and make it clickable ,i have read ListView andtried to use it,but i have data in something like below code,how will i add to adapter? from this list i will loop and get messages say list.get(i).getMessage(); which has to be displayed and there are multiple messages.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminderlist);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,   R.layout.reminderlayout);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminderlayout);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        ArrayList<GetReminder> list = (ArrayList<GetReminder>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("reminderList");
        System.out.println("size is >>>"+list.size());
        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your custom adapter parametrized with `GetReminder`. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view) for example. Than you can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<GetReminder> list = (ArrayList<GetReminder>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("reminderList");
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, 0);
adapter.addAll(list)
```

or just pass your list as a third parameter in MyCustomAdapter constructor.

Comment: i am going to get messages from list like...list.get(i).getMessage(); and they are 'n' number of messages to be displayed in list,whether your code will work out?

Comment: Please, check getView method in example was given by me. Each call of this method represent 1 row in your list. Here you have to write your realisation how to show information from your list in your ListView.

Comment: ok ,i went through it,i even found the complete example at the end,but in that how to implement onClick event

Comment: You found? I gave you a link for complete example. 'listView.setOnItemClickListener' in order to assighn on item click listener.

Comment: i am following has you said  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view last post from Louis,stil working on

Comment: RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'  ....,getting this exception

Comment: There is one more copy-past from some source without understanding (or even efforts) what are you doing. Can't help in this case.

Comment: yes i tried this code in a sample app on my side to understand,but after applying to my prj it caused issue...,i am a newbie to this android so i took over.

Comment: All this our discussion is not related to this question. If you have further question - ask it in separate one. This one is answered (at least I think so)

Comment: Can you please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215730/server-not-able-to-read-parameters-while-making-a-webservice-connection

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<GetReminder>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.reminderlayout,(GetReminder[]) list.toArray()));
```

considering this code is in `onCreate()` method of your class that extends `ListActivity`

Comment: i am going to get messages from list like...list.get(i).getMessage(); and they are 'n' number of messages to be displayed in list,whether your code will work out?

Comment: In that case iterate over your list get all messages store in in an array and pass that to the Adapters constructor.

Comment: u mean store in string[]

Comment: Yes if that's what `getMessage()` returns.

Comment: it wil return me a string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215730/server-not-able-to-read-parameters-while-making-a-webservice-connection any idea on this?